# Issue with rendering React JSX using if conditional inside map

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering, es6-map

case 1) I am trying to conditionally render using map and a ternary operator. Here I am iterating over an array of objects and then render only first six of them. Trying to achieve the same, but it does not seem like working.

Help would be appreciated

### OBJECT

```
const recentEventsData = [
  { key: "01", text: "AAA", timestamp: "11:52:27:02 02-11-2019" },
  { key: "02", text: "BBB", timestamp: "11:52:29:02 02-11-2019" },
  { key: "03", text: "CCC", timestamp: "11:52:30:02 02-11-2019" }
];
```

### Inside render()

```
{
  recentEventsData.map((data, index) => {
    {
      index < 6 ? (
        <div key={index}>
          //Want the transformed output here , that is fourth value from object
          <p>{data.text}</p>
          <p>{data.timestamp}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ) : null;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `{}` inside JSX when you want to inject a JavaScript expression, so inside the function given to `map` there is no need to create a new block.

Since you have given the function a body, you also need to explicitly return the result.

```
{recentEventsData.map((data, index) => {
  return index < 6 ? (
    <div key={index}>
      <p>{data.text}</p>
      <p>{data.timestamp}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
  ) : null;
})}
```

Instead of checking the index and returning `null` for the rest of the elements, you can instead `slice` out the elements you are interested in before using `map`.

```
{recentEventsData.slice(0, 6).map((data, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <p>{data.text}</p>
    <p>{data.timestamp}</p>
    <hr />
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) and remove the inner `{}` brackets as `.map()` needs to return values to work.

> The **splice()** method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

```
{
  recentEventsData.slice(0, 6).map((data, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{data.text}</p>
          <p>{data.timestamp}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value by using return keyword.

Comment: If you could please edit the code snippet, that'd be great

Comment: @velsonjr Welcome